# How to specify conditional plots within a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I have written a function that fits a separate model for several variables and stores the fitted values and confidence intervals in a list called `fitmod`. The function then finds local min and max values within a range of the fitted values, and temporarily stores them in `Loc.Min` and `Loc.Max`. Next it produces a line plot for the fitted values each variable, and marks points for the local min and max (only if they fall within a certain range of the fitted values index, as determined by: `fitmod[which(fitmod$idx %in% Loc.Min), ]`. Here is an example of how it is written within the function (just using two variables `Var1` and `Var2` for the example):

```r
#Var1 plot
    Loc.Min <- which(diff(sign(diff(fitmod$Var1.fit)))==2)+1
    Loc.Max <- which(diff(sign(diff(fitmod$Var1.fit)))==-2)+1  
Var1plot<-
    ggplot(fitmod, aes(x=idx, y=Var1.fit))+
      geom_line()+
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Var1.lci, ymax=Var1.uci), alpha =0.3)+
      labs(x=element_blank(), y="Var1")+
      geom_point(data=fitmod[which(fitmod$idx %in% Loc.Min), ], aes(color="Local.Minima"), size=3)+
      geom_point(data=fitmod[which(fitmod$idx %in% Loc.Max), ], aes(color="Local.Maxima"), size=3)+
      scale_color_manual(values=list("red","blue"))

#Var2 plot
    Loc.Min <- which(diff(sign(diff(fitmod$Var2.fit)))==2)+1
    Loc.Max <- which(diff(sign(diff(fitmod$Var2.fit)))==-2)+1  
Var2plot<-
    ggplot(fitmod, aes(x=idx, y=Var2.fit))+
      geom_line()+
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Var2.lci, ymax=Var2.uci), alpha =0.3)+
      labs(x=element_blank(), y="Var2")+
      geom_point(data=fitmod[which(fitmod$idx %in% Loc.Min), ], aes(color="Local.Minima"), size=3)+
      geom_point(data=fitmod[which(fitmod$idx %in% Loc.Max), ], aes(color="Local.Maxima"), size=3)+
      scale_color_manual(values=list("red","blue"))
```

This works perfectly as long as it picks up at least one value for both `Loc.Min` and `Loc.Max`. Yet occasionally there are no values that fall within the range for one of the variables, so I suppose one of the: `[which(fitmod$idx %in% Loc.Max), ]` expressions defaults to NULL, and I get an error message that says `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x and y`. 
So how can I change this code to make it ignore either of the `geom_point()` lines (and corresponding `scale_color_manual()` call that pairs with it) if the `which()` expression equals zero?

Comment: I think you can use `if` for this? Just check beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing a lot of similarities in your call to `geom_point()` for both minima and maxima in `Var1plot` and `Var2plot`.  Without your data, it's hard to test this, but I'm thinking something like this would work.  My approach was to write a function that will either:

1. Return an empty list if your subsetted data has no rows, or
2. Return the proper `geom_point` call (as a list).

`loc.minmax` is either the `Loc.Min` or `Loc.Max`, and `label_name` is the label of the `color=` aesthetic for the `geom_point` call as a character string:

```
my_points <- function(loc.minmax, label_name) {
  return_list <- list()
  checkframe <- fitmod[which(fitmod$idx %in% loc.minmax), ]
  if(nrow(checkframe)!=0) {
    return_list <- geom_point(data=checkframe, aes(color=label_name), size=3)
  }
  return(return_list)
}
```

You can add `geom` and other `ggplot2` calls directly to a plot if you format them as a list, so you can then simply add the function into your `ggplot()` calls.  Here's the example of usage for `Var2plot` that should work (in theory):

```
Var2plot<-
  ggplot(fitmod, aes(x=idx, y=Var2.fit))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Var2.lci, ymax=Var2.uci), alpha =0.3)+
  labs(x=element_blank(), y="Var2")+
  my_points(Loc.Min, 'Local.Minima') +
  my_points(Loc.Max, 'Local.Maxima') +
  scale_color_manual(values=list("red","blue"))
```

Let me know if that works...